# How set float left configuration for items in columns of the fieldset using extJs?

Tags: extjs, css-float, fieldset

I am trying to left-align the contents of the columns in fieldset. Code is below:

```
items: [{
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Level 1000',
            layout: 'column',
            width: '100%',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                width: '50%',
                items: [{
                    labelWidth: 'auto',
                    xtype: 'checkbox',
                    fieldLabel: 'State institutions',
                    name: 'IsTreasuryDepartments'
                }, {
                    labelWidth: 'auto',
                    xtype: 'checkbox',
                    fieldLabel: 'Autonomous Institutions',
                    name: 'IsAutonomousDepartmenys'
                }, {
                    labelWidth: 'auto',
                    xtype: 'checkbox',
                    fieldLabel: 'Other legal entity',
                    name: 'IsOtherJuridicalPerson'
                }, ]
            }, {
                xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                width: '50%',
                items: [{
                    labelWidth: 'auto',
                    xtype: 'checkbox',
                    fieldLabel: 'Budgetary institutions',
                    name: 'IsBudgetDepartments'
                }, {
                    labelWidth: 'auto',
                    xtype: 'checkbox',
                    fieldLabel: 'Unitary enterprise',
                    name: 'IsUnitaryEnterprise'
                }]
            }]
        }
```

result:

[image]

I have tried to use labelAlign: 'right' or labelStyle: 'float:right' for each item, but it is doesn't work. How set float: right for labels and checkboxes in columns and receive following?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `width` or `labelWidth` with a number value.

Example:

```js
{
  xtype: "fieldset",
  title: "Level 1000",
  layout: "column",
  width: "100%",
  items: [{
      xtype: "fieldcontainer",
      width: "50%",
      defaults: {
          width: 300
      },
      items: [{
          labelWidth: "auto",
          xtype: "checkbox",
          fieldLabel: "State institutions",
          name: "IsTreasuryDepartments"
      }, {
          labelWidth: "auto",
          xtype: "checkbox",
          fieldLabel: "Autonomous Institutions",
          name: "IsAutonomousDepartmenys"
      }, {
          labelWidth: "auto",
          xtype: "checkbox",
          fieldLabel: "Other legal entity",
          name: "IsOtherJuridicalPerson"
      }, ]
  }, {
      xtype: "fieldcontainer",
      width: "50%",
       defaults: {
          width: 300
      },
      items: [{
          labelWidth: 130,
          xtype: "checkbox",
          fieldLabel: "Budgetary institutions",
          name: "IsBudgetDepartments"
      }, {
          labelWidth: 130,
          xtype: "checkbox",
          fieldLabel: "Unitary enterprise",
          name: "IsUnitaryEnterprise"
      }]
  }]
}
```

Example on https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/327j

Comment: Yes it works, but in my case required solution a little bit different. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case works following:

```
        items: [{
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Level 1000',
            layout: 'column',
            width: '100%',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
                layout: 'vbox',
                width: '50%',
                layout: 'vbox',
                defaults: {
                    labelAlign: 'right',
                    labelWidth: 170
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'checkbox',
                    fieldLabel: 'State institutions',
                    name: 'IsTreasuryDepartments'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'checkbox',
                    fieldLabel: 'Autonomous Institutions',
                    name: 'IsAutonomousDepartmenys'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'checkbox',
                    fieldLabel: 'Other legal entity',
                    name: 'IsOtherJuridicalPerson'
                }, ]
            }, {
                xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
                layout: 'vbox',
                width: '50%',
                defaults: {
                    labelAlign: 'right',
                    labelWidth: 170
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'checkbox',
                    fieldLabel: 'Other legal entity sdfsd',
                    name: 'IsBudgetDepartments'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'checkbox',
                    fieldLabel: 'Unitary enterprise',
                    name: 'IsUnitaryEnterprise'
                }]
            }]
        }]
```